# Apple patent application already granted to another

Tags: apple

In reference to the patent: [US20140206209](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140206209)

Appears to be the same as US7458825 B2 granted to Walletex Microelectronics in 2008.

Answer (score 1):

I briefly looked at both documents and, while the are trying to accomplish the same goal, it looks like they are doing it in different ways. At least that's what I get from reading the first claims.

Answer (score 0):

Patents can be sold, owners can change. I didn't look up if thats what happened here, but you can do that in the history of the patent (for example at espacenet).